# Explanation of ROC data output in SAS Logistic Regression

Tags: sas

I have run the logistic regression in SAS on binary data set available online.

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv

below is the sample output:

```
_PROB_   _POS_ _NEG_ _FALPOS_   _FALNEG_    _SENSIT_    _1MSPEC_
0.941210953 1   127 0   272 0.003663004 0
0.928012776 2   127 0   271 0.007326007 0
0.927643195 3   127 0   270 0.010989011 0
0.925136849 4   127 0   269 0.014652015 0
0.921044923 5   127 0   268 0.018315018 0
0.91222972  6   127 0   267 0.021978022 0
0.903114817 7   127 0   266 0.025641026 0
0.902970992 8   127 0   265 0.029304029 0
0.901363504 9   127 0   264 0.032967033 0
0.897147605 10  127 0   263 0.036630037 0
0.891836956 11  127 0   262 0.04029304  0
0.891466706 12  127 0   261 0.043956044 0
0.89118058  13  127 0   260 0.047619048 0
0.887809967 14  127 0   259 0.051282051 0
0.886286835 15  127 0   258 0.054945055 0
0.884789828 15  126 1   258 0.054945055 0.007874016
0.883748771 16  126 1   257 0.058608059 0.007874016
0.883658492 17  126 1   256 0.062271062 0.007874016
0.883005072 18  126 1   255 0.065934066 0.007874016
0.881642156 19  126 1   254 0.06959707  0.007874016
0.881636206 20  126 1   253 0.073260073 0.007874016
0.881161673 21  126 1   252 0.076923077 0.007874016
0.880570499 21  125 2   252 0.076923077 0.015748032
0.879641459 22  125 2   251 0.080586081 0.015748032
0.878868995 23  125 2   250 0.084249084 0.015748032
```

...

How should I interpret this and how these values are calculated?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. Is there a specific term or concept you don't understand here? Each row in the above represents the classifier's performance for a specified decision threshold (_prob_). It tell you how many 0s and 1s were correctly predicted at different thresholds.

Answer (score 5):

As the writer of the first logistic regression procedure in SAS I feel quite guilty about putting measures such as proportion "classified" "correctly" in the procedure, and when the procedure was re-written by SAS Institute, they carried along the measures I had programmed.  Measures such as classification accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity should never have been applied to logistic regression.  Logistic regression is all about estimating probabilities, and any measures you choose should be functions of estimated probabilities and observed outcomes, and should use no binning (categorization) of any kind.